# how to save an image file in db?

Tags: java, database, image

I have a desktop programm and I must to save image files with different formats and different sizes in db. Any idea how can I do that? anyone can help me, please?

Comment: You can't store image directly in database, instead you can store image in db by using binary format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Save Image into Database by **Converting it into binary** as follow:

```
public void saveImage(File file){
        try {
            String img_id=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Image ID");
            FileInputStream fis=null;
            String query="insert into image(image_id,image) values (?,?)";
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:image");
            PreparedStatement pstm=con.prepareStatement(query);
            fis=new FileInputStream(file);
            pstm.setString(1, img_id);       
            pstm.setBinaryStream(2, (InputStream)fis, (int)file.length());
            pstm.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image Successfully Uploaded to Database");
            pstm.close();
            con.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception Occured: "+ex);
        }
    }
```

And Retrieve it by again making Image from binary and Save it on some physical Location:

```
public void getSavedImages(){
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:image");
            PreparedStatement pstm1 = con.prepareStatement("select * from image");
            ResultSet rs1 = pstm1.executeQuery();
            while(rs1.next()) {
                InputStream fis1;
                FileOutputStream fos;
                String image_id;
                try {
                    fis1 = rs1.getBinaryStream("image");
                    image_id=rs1.getString("image_id");
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Path to "C:\\" + (image_id) + "Your Extension(.jpg/.gif)"));
                    int c;
                    while ((c = fis1.read()) != -1) {
                        fos.write(c);
                    }
                    fis1.close();
                    fos.close();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            } 
            pstm1.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception Occured:"+ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @temcheg : If you find it useful You, can Upvote it and Mark as Accepted... :)

Comment: thank you, codeMaker, so much!

Comment: @temcheg:(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)[http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work]

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should just store the address of the image file in the database.

Achieves the same end and the database doesn't become bloated.

Answer (score 0):

As a BLOB: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object

The exact implementation depends on your database system.

Answer (score 0):

it is the most common problem for novice developer.
The Best solution is...you save the image in folder and save the filepath in database and after that you can access the file using this  filepath.